# Remove duplicate rows in R data frame, based on a date field and another field

Tags: r, date, dataframe, duplicates

New to R, but learning to handle db data and hit a wall.

I want to remove duplicate rows/observations from a table, based on two criteria: A user ID field and a date field that indicates the last time there was a change to the user, so the most recent dated row.

My truncated data set would look like the following:

```
UID    | DateLastChange
1      |  01/01/2016
1      |  01/03/2016
2      |  01/14/2015
3      |  02/15/2014
3      |  03/15/2016
```

I would like to end up with:

```
UID    | DateLastChange
1      |  01/03/2016
2      |  01/14/2015
3      |  03/15/2016
```

I have attempted to use duplicate or unique, but they don't seem to fully embrace the ability to be selective. I can conceive of the possibility to build a new table with unique UIDs, then left join in some way to only match with the most recent date.

Any advice would be much appreciated. 
Scott

Comment: This is just a `duplicated` operation if it is in the order shown - `dat[!duplicated(dat$UID, fromLast=TRUE),]`

Comment: Thanks for the edit to the post. As you may have read, that was my first post to SO, so I haven't really figured out how to end up with neat tables. TY. SW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr - data can be in any order

```
require(dplyr)
dat$DateLastChange <- strptime(dat$DateLastChange, "%m/%d%Y")) 
dat %>% group_by(UID) %>% summarize(DateLastChange = max(DateLastChange))
```

Comment: Epi99, thanks for the quick response. It returns an error indicating that the date format is wrong. "Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :   column 'EmploymentStatusChangeDate' has unsupported class : POSIXlt, POSIXt. I attempted to find a way to specify this as POSIXct, but have yet to find appropriate usage. I see where you are heading however with this and will keep plugging away.

Comment: Your sample data is in plain text - so the strptime() is to parse the text date format into a datetime object, so that max() can do a valid compare. Your data frame may aready be in a date or time format, in which case you don't need the line that includes strptime(). 

This is why generally recommend using dput to show your example data - then your reader can recreate exactly the data you have.

Comment: I will explore dput so we can all have the same apples/apples comparison on the data. Yesterday I worked through converting the date from character to a date and the max() comparison actually worked, so thank you.

Comment: This works only for the given example, however, if you have additional columns you want to use a filter instead: `dat %>% group_by(UID) %>% filter(Date == max(Date))`.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(UID, -as.IDate(DateLastChange, "%m/%d/%Y")), head(.SD, 1), by = UID]
#     UID DateLastChange
#1:   1     01/03/2016
#2:   2     01/14/2015
#3:   3     03/15/2016
```

---

Or using `duplicated`

```
setDT(df1)[order(UID, -as.IDate(DateLastChange, "%m/%d/%Y"))][!duplicated(UID)]
```

Comment: Does this work for randomly ordered DateLastChange entries or do they have to be in chronological order, as in OP's example?

Comment: @questionmark In the `i`, we are `order`ing the column 'DateLastChange` after converting to `Date` class.  It should work for randomly ordered.  Only change that may need is the format `%m/%d/%Y` if it is not in that order of month/day/Year

Comment: Thank makes perfect sense! Thanks @akrun!